# Is there any benefit in opening green and blue or chests when Kratos is at full health or mana?

Tags: god-of-war

[image]

God of War still allows consuming green and blue or chests when Kratos' health and magic reserves are maxed out. Is there any benefit whatsoever using these consumables you may need later (the game isn't strictly linear and some areas are revisited)?

Not to be confused with [the red orb chests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2cxl.jpg) (points to upgrade abilities).

Comment: Not really an answer, but GoW is an action game, and resource management is not really part of the game play. I used to "conserve" resources, but I ended up not using 95% of the game's pick up. Just spam your skills and pick up whatever you come across and not worry about it...